# Owl-Carousel transition backslide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I am trying to add backslide animation of `Owl Carousel` by below code. But backslide animation is not adding to my template. I tried in many ways, but still can't figure it out.

[demo](https://github.com/skyy-is-limit/Owl-Carousel-Test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you are using `owl.carousel v2.3.4` and `owl.transitions.css v1.3.2` which are incompatible. Downgrading `owl.carousel` to `v1.3.3` should help to resolve the issue

Comment: @komron , yes im using latest version of owl-carousel. I dont want to downgrade, in this situation, how can i  `get owl.transitions.css` which is compitable with latest version?

Comment: @RubelAhmed it was Y. Komusov who gave you an answer, i edited his answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `owl.carousel v2.3.4` animation is managed by `animateIn` and `animateOut` properties - [reference](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/animate.html) . You just need to use appropriate CSS classes from `owl.transition.css` file. Example below should work.

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        slideSpeed : 1000,
        paginationSpeed : 500,
        singleItem:true,
        items: 1,
        navigation : false,
        animateIn:"owl-backSlide-in",
        animateOut: "owl-backSlide-out",
        afterAction:function(){$(window).trigger("resize");},
    });
```

Comment: @Y Komusov where can i get this `owl.transition.css` latest file ?

Comment: Use the one that already in your [repo](https://github.com/skyy-is-limit/Owl-Carousel-Test/blob/master/css/owl.transitions.css)